# Can a company monitor the workstations without telling the users?

Tags: productivity, work-time

It's legal to track user activity throught a local spy software or proxies like SonicWall and don't telling them that they are being tracked?

Comment: Legal questons are out of scope and it would depend on the locality anyway.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's legal or not, you shouldn't be doing anything on your company workstation that you wouldn't want them to know about.

Comment: In general everything you do while working is work product for your company.  They can do what they want with it.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the legal environment where you are.

Having said that, in most US states, this is legal, and I've worked places where this was done.  The company network, and the company computers on it, are company property, so there's really no reasonable expectation of privacy - or so goes the legal reasoning that allows unannounced monitoring.

Really, when you're using someone else's property, it seems to me like you should assume you're being watched at all times anyway.

Comment: And to add, in many cases your employment contract states that you are subject to monitoring while using company computers and network.

Comment: What is and what isn't a reasonable expectation of privacy is a legal matter, and I don't think any of us is qualified to comment on it.

Comment: @DavidK Yeah, almost everywhere I've worked had that stipulation in the employee handbook, or other documents.  Seems to me that would qualify as "disclosure" of the monitoring, however, and that in this question, there weren't any documents that warned about the use of of a webfiltering proxy.

Comment: @Yannis "Reasonable expectation of privacy" may be a legal term, but it's also something everyone deals with in their everyday life, in an extra-legal sense as well.  And in that sense, everyone and everyone is qualified to comment on it, and everyone's opinions are used to form the political/legal environment and societal expectations around which activities and locations are private, and which ones are not.